# Display specific information for logged in user in Express js + mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

Ok, somehow this question hasn't been raised nor did someone make an explanation about this problem: How can logged in user - User a - display his specific user information? I'm using Express js and PUG template engine.

A user - User A - enters user information in a form input, this input is stored in mongoDB and retrieved inside the form (e.g. value=user_info[name]) - that's DONE. However, how should this user data displayed only to - User A.

I assume, this is somehow related to sessionId - similar to app.js: req.session.userId = user._id ??! - but I'm not clear about the procedure. I hope that someone is able to demystify this, and provide an executable action plan.

Since this issue wasn't covered in any explanation / Tutorial etc. across the internet, it might be helpful for future readers as well. Thanks a lot in advance.

index.js - routing / authentication

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var mid = require('../middleware');
var passport = require('passport');


// GET /dashboard
router.get('/dashboard', mid.requiresLogin, function(req, res, next) {
  User.findById(req.session.userId)
      .exec(function (error, user) {
        if (error) {
          return next(error);
        } else {
          return res.render('dashboard', { title: 'Dashboard', name: user.username });
        }
      });
});

// GET /logout
router.get('/logout', function(req, res, next){
  if (req.session) {
    // delete session object
    req.session.destroy(function(err){
      if(err){
        return next(err);
      } else {
        return res.redirect('/');
      }
    });
  }
});

// GET /login
router.get('/login', mid.loggedOut, function(req, res, next) {
  return res.render('login', { title: 'Log In'});
});

// POST /login
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
    User.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password, function (error, user) {
      if (error || !user) {
        var err = new Error('Wrong email or password.');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
      }  else {
        req.session.userId = user._id;
        return res.redirect('/dashboard');
      }
    });
  } else {
    var err = new Error('Email and password are required.');
    err.status = 401;
    return next(err);
  }
});

// GET /register
router.get('/register', mid.loggedOut, function(req, res, next) {
  return res.render('register', { title: 'Sign Up' });
});

// POST /register
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.body.username &&
    req.body.email &&
    req.body.password &&
    req.body.confirmPassword) {

      // confirm that user typed same password twice
      if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirmPassword) {
        var err = new Error('Passwords do not match.');
        err.status = 400;
        return next(err);
      }

      // create object with form input
      var userData = {
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      };

      // use schema's `create` method to insert document into Mongo
      User.create(userData, function (error, user) {
        if (error) {
          return next(error);
        } else {
          req.session.userId = user._id;
          return res.redirect('/dashboard');
        }
      });

    } else {
      var err = new Error('All fields required.');
      err.status = 400;
      return next(err);
    }
});
```

app.js - HINT: some code is commented out and not relevant

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('express-session')
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var User = require('./models/user');
var User_info = require('./models/user_info');
var app = express();


// mongodb connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/socialempireclub");
var db = mongoose.connection;

// mongo error
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

// use sessions for tracking logins
app.use(session({
  secret: 'treehouse loves you',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db
  })
}));

// make user ID available in templates
app.use(function (req, res, next){
  res.locals.currentUser = req.session.userId;
  next();
});

// parse incoming requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// serve static files from /public
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// include routes
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);

/*app.post('/new', function(req, res){
  new User_info({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    streetAddress: req.body.streetAddress,
    city: req.body.city,
    state: req.body.state,
    zip: req.body.zip,
    country: req.body.country
  }).save(function(err, User_info){
      if(err) res.json(err);
      else res.redirect('/profileretrieve');
  });
});*/

/*app.get('/profileretrieve', function(req, res){
    User_info.find({}, function(err, docs){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else    res.render('profileretrieve', {user_infos: docs});
    });
});*/

 /*app.get('/user_info/:id', function(req, res){
  User_info.find({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, docs){
    if(err) res.json(err);
    else res.render('show', {user_infos: docs[0]});
  });
});*/

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('File Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
// define as the last app.use callback
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

// listen on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Express app listening on port 3000');
});
```

user.js - Schema 1

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

// authenticate input against database documents
UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function(email, password, callback) {
  User.findOne({ email: email })
    .exec(function (error, user){
      if (error) {
        return callback(error);
      } else if ( !user ) {
        var err = new Error('User not found.');
        err.status = 401;
        return callback(err);
      }
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(error, result){
        if (result === true) {
          return callback(null, user);
        } else {
          return callback();
        }
      })
    });
}
// hash password before saving to database
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash){
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    user.password = hash;
    next();
  })
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

user_info.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserinfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  streetAddress: String,
  city: String,
  state: String,
  zip: String,
  country: String
});

var User_info = mongoose.model('User_info', UserinfoSchema);
module.exports = User_info;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I have it set up is that I have RESTful endpoints to load user information, and each of those routes checks for session information when called from the frontend. So:

```
var User = require('./models/user');
var router = require('express').Router();

// hand-rolled middleware function
function ensureAuth(req, res, next) {
  // isAuthenticated() is a Passport.js method on the request object
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  } else {
    return res.json(401, {error: 'user must be logged in.'});
  }
}

// get logged in user
router.get('/user', ensureAuth, function (req, res) {
  // req.user should be defined here because of the ensureAuth middleware
  var id = req.user.id;

  User.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return res.json(400, {message: `user ${id} not found.`});

    // make sure you omit sensitive user information 
    // on this object before sending it to the client.
    res.json(user);
  });
});

// other routes or whatever
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that gives me a starting idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out, here's the solution, if someone needs it:

```
app.post('/about', function(req, res){
  Userinfo.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.session.userId }, {$set:{ firstName:
    req.body.firstName, lastName: req.body.lastName, streetAddress: req.body.streetAddress,
    city: req.body.city, state: req.body.state, zip: req.body.zip, country: req.body.country,
    postedBy: req.session.userId}}, {upsert: true, new: true}, function(err, Userinfo){
      if(err){
          if (err) res.json(err);
      }
      console.log(Userinfo);
  });
});
```

Comment: Beware, you should sanitize your info before storing it in the db. use something like [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) before storing untrusted information.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. Do you know how I can display the stored & retrieved informations in the form input value, such as value=userinfo.firstName ? When someone submitted the info, they should be able to see it, displayed in the form input field. Is this possible in Node.js?

Comment: like when they return to the page later, you want to pre-populate the fields? It depends on your templating solution or if you're loading JSON on the front end. If you're using templates and rendering on the server side, do something like `<input name="firstName" value="<?= userinfo.firstName ?>" />` or you'd set the values manually with js after loading your json or with whatever front-end framework you've chosen.

Comment: Ok, I came across the solution I was seeking for today by accident: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/yYRkM/